# Include other datasets from xml

Tags: java, testing, junit, dbunit

DBUnit recommends using [Small Datasets](http://www.dbunit.org/bestpractices.html#smalldatasets) but I found no example where a small dataset is included in the dataset. I need something similar to (pseudocode)

```
<dataset>
<!-- this tag is what I am looking for... ;-)-->
     <include_other_datasets_which_is_shared_between_different_datasets datasetname="other.xml"/>
<!-- normal xmldataset-definition begins... -->
<table name="foo">...</table>
</dataset>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such feature exist in dbUnit as far as I know, and you don't really need that anyway.

Because you can simply execute an operation multiple time for different dataset.

```
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(conn, "first_table.xml");
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(conn, "second_table.xml");
```

or use [CompositeDataSet](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/CompositeDataSet.html) to combine mutiple dataset into one in runtime.

Comment: I do really need this feature because I wrote a small tool which uses db-unit. To use this tool I only have to provide the dataset to be inserted no java code needed. My solution now is: seperating the datasets by commas and then inserting them. CompositeDataSet looks promising anyway. Thank you